# Sortable, readable and standard time format for logs

Tags: sorting, datetime, logging, strptime

### Timestamp format in logs

Most log lines contain a timestamp and event description:

```
[When] [What]
```

e.g.:

```
[23/Jul/2013:19:35:11 +0000] Processing started.
[23/Jul/2013:19:36:11 +0000] Processed 1000 items.
[23/Jul/2013:19:37:11 +0000] Processing finished successfully.
```

I am trying to find a standard timestamp for my log lines. My criteria is:

1. **Human readable**. I want to easily understand when did the event happen.
2. **Alphabetically sortable**. When I `grep` events from a few files and sort them using POSIX `sort` or even word/excel, I want the alphabetical sort to adhere to chronological sort. For example, `[23/Jul/2012:19:35:11 +0000]` and `[22/Jul/2013:19:35:11 +0000]` are not sortable - the 2013 line would appear before the 2012 line.
3. **Easily parsable by all common languages**. The timestamp should be easily parsed using standard [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) if the log is processed by a script.

The only standard I've found so far is [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which has many variants (e.g. `2007-04-05T14:30Z` and `2007-03-01T13:00:00Z`), and lacks a definite standard for log line events.

**Could you recommend a standard timestamp format for log lines?**

Comment: [rfc 3339 defines a profile of ISO 8601](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5) that comes close to 1-3

Comment: Thanks. It recommends something like `1985-04-12T23:20:50.52Z` or `1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00`. The only thing I don't like is the `T` in the middle; the separation between date and time isn't clear enough. Perhaps I should use a space.

Comment: The rfc mentions that applications may use space instead of "T" for readability

Comment: Great, so I'll go for that. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

@J.F. Sebestian - Thanks for your comment.

After some research I chose [RFC 3339 / ISO 8601 in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), e.g.:

```
date -u "+[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z (%Z)]"       # Space separated with tz abbreviation
[2013-07-31 23:56:34+0000 (UTC)]                   

date -u "+[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%N %z (%Z)]"  # Space separated with nanoseconds and tz abbreviation
[2013-07-31 23:56:34.812572000 +0000 (UTC)]
```

Features:

- Sortable (Most significant date item is on the left)
- Readable
- Unambiguous, time zone clearly stated
- Delimited by `[`,`]`, useful for regexing the date away
- Easily parsable
- Accurate: uses nanoseconds (might be practically milliseconds on some machines, which is good enough)

I've also created a [nice github project that helps with date formatting](https://github.com/adamatan/date_formatting_examples) - feel free to take a look and suggest your own formats!

Answer (score 2):

The unix date command has such an option. Use

```
date -Iseconds
```

or

```
date -Ins
```

The manpage says:

```
   -I[FMT], --iso-8601[=FMT]
          output  date/time  in  ISO  8601  format.   FMT='date' for date only (the default),
          'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds', or 'ns' for date and time to  the  indicated  preci‐
          sion.  Example: 2006-08-14T02:34:56-0600
```